# Passwords On Remote Server Code Security

Tags: security, web

I am building a web app which will be sending out emails for sign up verification. I will be using https://github.com/RGBboy/express-mailer. I wanted to know whether it is safe for me to display the email password in the code and push it to the server (Heroku, AWS etc.) where the app is hosted. If not, what alternative methods should I use to 'hide' the password?

Comment: One thing I have seen, for example in wordpress, is to use a config.sample.php with empty/default values and then you save the "production" values in config.php and then add that file to the ignored files list (.gitignore I think? I dunno. I never use git.)

Answer (score 1):

It is usually considered bad practice to have plaintext secrets/credentials stored under version control. As that could lead to [security issues](http://chrishateswriting.com/post/84931829578/when-a-bad-day-gets-worsegetting-hacked-twice-in)

Usually these sorts of info are set as environment variables. Heroku has a [pretty straightforward way of doing this configuration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). You can either use their web admin, or set them via command line.

As for other cases, like your development setup, this could be done with the use of `.env` files, which are loaded and have its values exposed to your running code. Since `[express-mailer][2]` is a node application, I suggest using some npm package like [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) or [`node-env-file`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-env-file) automatically do this loading.I personally prefer `dotenv` which I feel is simpler.

You should also check out [this article](https://medium.com/@rafaelvidaurre/managing-environment-variables-in-node-js-2cb45a55195f#.jlsctp832) regarding the use of `.env` files. The basic idea is to have your `.gitignore`(or equivalent) to ignore your `.env` file, thus ensuring your secret credentials are never introduced in your version control. And then setup an `.env.sample` file to show the developer which data needs to be declared on said `.env` file.

Example:

**.env**

```
EMAIL=foo@bar.com
PASSWORD=AahUbf796
S3_TOKEN=ASVNS7843NCA87SDVNBRT9
```

**.env.sample**

```
EMAIL=<email to access the account>
PASSWORD=<secret password>
S3_TOKEN=<s3 token for application foobar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't ever store secrets in version control.

One alternative (which I personally like the best) is setting secrets as environment variables for your application in your production environment. Heroku I think supports this. This is also the approach that for example Rails takes. Dev/test "secrets" (which are not actually real credentials to anything valuable) can still of course be stored in your VCS.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to encrypt the user credentials in your source code and decrypt them from your source code.